# Creating a View table that override NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, request

I am having trouble creating a view using SQL server 2008. I have several tables that looks like that:

*Parent Table*:

```
+----+------+
| id | date |
+----+------+
| 1  | 2010 |
+----+------+
```

*Child Table*:

```
+----+------+-----------+
| id | date | ParentID  |
+----+------+-----------+
| 1  | NULL |         1 |
| 2  | 2011 |         1 |
+----+------+-----------+
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a view that would look like that (based on the two previous examples) :

*Child Table CustomView*:

```
+----+------+----------+
| id | date | ParentID |
+----+------+----------+
|  1 | 2010 |        1 |
|  2 | 2011 |        1 |
+----+------+----------+
```

Basically, the Child table have some fields that should be 'inherited' from its Parent when its value is NULL (first row of Child table: '2010' is retrieved). 
Otherwise, it should just display its value (second row of Child table: '2011').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use coalesce. you can have as many parameters as you like. it returns the first one that is not null. when all of them are null, it returns null

```
select c.[id],
       coalesce(c.[date], p.[date]) [date],
       c.parentid
  from child c
  join parent p
    on p.[id] = c.parentid
```

Answer (score 0):

Use IsNull function in your SELECT

```
SELECT Child.Id,
       IsNull(Child.Date, Parent.Date),
       ParentId
  FROM Child 
  JOIN Parent ON Parent.Id = Child.ParentId
```